# Best way to run a script that takes a long time (48 hours) to run on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am an academic researcher. I need to get data from a social media platform for a large number of users. Due to API restrictions, it takes a very long time (~48 hours) to get this data for all users. As of now, I write this data to a CSV file as I go with one line per user.

My lab has access and many credits for AWS. Assuming this script just needs to be run once a week, what is the best way to do it in AWS? And I assume I should use a database instead of a CSV file -- what options are there for setting that up?

Comment: This is rather broad but I would think that a small EC2 could run the script, perhaps dump the CSV file to S3 and shut down.  You'll want an AWS [AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) or to use [EC2 user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) to setup and run the script.  A database is certainly possible with [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) but it's not clear what your requirements are.  That would increase cost and complexity but, again, is it worth it?

Comment: Might be useful: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can achieve this:

1. You could set up a cron job on an instance you keep deployed throughout. This could be a very small, inexpensive instance like t2.small or t3.medium. The job runs once a week.
2. If you don't want to keep the instance deployed, write a small script which creates an EC2 instance every week and puts your script on the instance where it runs. And the script itself and send AWS the request to terminate the instance on a successful run (not recommended)
3. If you can break your task into steps, AWS Lambda is the way to go. Look at [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) here.
4. I would recommend looking at other solutions, e.g. [AWS Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html). It is serverless and allows running arbitrary long tasks in Docker containers.

Furthermore, a handy workaround (usually) to the API restriction is to ping from multiple clients or IPs and merge the results later.